# iterate over yaml array in rust

Tags: rust, yaml

Hi i have a yaml array that i would like to iterate over in rust
this is the yaml array:

```yaml
schedules: 
  - 8:00-9:10
  - 9:30-10:40
  - 11:00-12:10
  - 16:20-17:30
  - 15:00-16-10
```

and this is the code i have already got:

```rust
extern crate yaml_rust;
use std::fs::read_to_string;
use yaml_rust::{YamlLoader};
fn main() {
    let config = read_to_string("config.yaml").unwrap();
    let docs = YamlLoader::load_from_str(&config).unwrap();
    let doc = &docs[0];
    let schedules = &doc["schedules"];
}
```

how would I go about iterating `schedules`?

i have tried turning it to a hash map (using `.as_hash().unwrap()` as other posts i saw suggested) but that says:
`` thread 'main' panicked at 'called `Option::unwrap()` on a `None` value', src/main.rs:8:49 ``

Comment: Use [`as_vec`](https://docs.rs/yaml-rust/0.4.5/yaml_rust/yaml/enum.Yaml.html#method.as_vec) instead, as you are trying to iterate over an array, not an object/hashmap.

Comment: i am now getting `&&std::vec::Vec<yaml_rust::Yaml> is not an iterator` after i unwrap it for some reason. why is that? isn't `Vec` an iterator?

Comment: fixed by `schedules.to_vec()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`yaml_rust` represents arrays as vectors. You can convert a YAML node into a `Vec` with the [`as_vec`](https://docs.rs/yaml-rust/0.4.5/yaml_rust/yaml/enum.Yaml.html#method.as_vec) method. If the node is not an array, `as_vec` will return `None`:

```rust
for schedule in schedules.as_vec().unwrap() {
    schedule.do_stuff()
}
```